# Detecting the rpm of a wheel using Image Processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi3

I have started learning image processing recently and testing myself by doing various hobby projects. So one project is about detecting the rpm of a rotating beam using the real-time camera feedback. I am using raspberry pi with an attached camera. To track the beam, I have attached one color which I can distinguish easily. I am successful in doing that. The program for this is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.h264')

r = [290,560,5000,200]

lower = np.array([30,30,70])
upper = np.array([37,37,85])

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is not None:
        imgcrop = frame[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
        hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(imgcrop,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(imgcrop, lower, upper)
        kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
        img_erode =  cv2.dilate(mask,kernel, iterations=10)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_erode, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        hull = []

        for i in range(len(contours)):
            hull.append(cv2.convexHull(contours[i], False))
        drawing = np.zeros((img_erode.shape[0], img_erode.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)

        for i in range(len(hull)):
            M = cv2.moments(hull[i])

            try:
                cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
                cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
                cv2.circle(drawing, (cX, cY), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
    
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With the above program , I am able to track the color alone on the image and plotting a center point of it. Now, I want to use this data to calculate the rpm.

My idea was to find the center point of the rotation using three point method, followed by the radius.

Use this data with `V= r*W` , where r is the radius and `V` is the velocity of the points, to compute the  `W` , rpm of the beam, is the main idea.

But this is not working. I don't know how to proceed further. If you can give me better guidance, it would be very useful.

The camera settings are as follows:

```
Resolution : 1920X1080
FPS : 10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to share your video please? Dropbox, Google Drive or somesuch.

Comment: "this is not working" is not a very useful description. also 10fps is a pretty low frame rate. what is your rpm value?

Comment: @Piglet the rpm is around 60. I need to use 10 fps because the raspberry camera , if set at full resolution, can go only up to 15 fps.

Comment: One approach is as follows: you track the centroid of the colored region; its x coordinate over time will form a sinusoid (as will the y coordinate). Using the FFT of this signal, you can find out what its frequency is.

Comment: Unless you can determine that the colour has moved passed a position and returned to the same position. I'm not smart enough to figure it out haha... if you're counting rotations, then you'd just can't each time it passes and the time passed and the number of times it passes in a minute is the rpm not sure you need to care about the frames as the frames to equate to time passed.But I could be wrong. I'd start by putting a dot on the wheel, if possible. and do was I said. Let us kow how you get on

Comment: @CrisLuengo This solution seems interesting. Since I already have experience with FFT, i will give it a shot . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code so that you remember the previous centroid (just `cX`) and calculate the displacement of the centroid between frames, you will see that it alternates between being positive (when moving right) and negative (when moving left).

You can get the time in seconds since the last change between positive/negative, using:

```
cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)*1000
```

that tells you the time for half a revolution, so double it and you have the period and can calculate the rpm as `60/period`.

You can ignore small displacements so it still works if the wheel is moving very very slowly.

You can also smooth the values by averaging over a few samples.

You can also do the same for the `cY` value to improve the accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for giving this information. I will try this!